# Fire Elfinder Error Dialog from Command

Tags: javascript, jquery, elfinder

I am working on making my own command ([view commands](https://github.com/Studio-42/elFinder/tree/2.x/js/commands)) for [elFinder](https://github.com/Studio-42/elFinder), and it works pretty good.

The only thing that I have a problem with is when I do my custom ajax call to the connector, the error doesn't popup. It is valid JSON error output.

I was thinking if it somehow was possible to fire the error dialog myself from the command file?

I'm trying to do this from inside the `this.exec = function(data) { ... }` function in my command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error call should be like this within that function. `this.fm.error()` or `fm.error()` in this case is used to fire the error dialog.

```
this.exec = function(data) {
    var fm = this.fm,
    dfrd  = $.Deferred()
        .fail(function(error) {
            fm.error(error);
        })
    return dfrd;
}
```